# Receiving corrupted Stream on Server

Tags: java, spring, stream, remoting

I've an application that sends requests to a Server using Spring Remoting (HttpInvokerServiceExporter). Normaly that works fine. But some Requests causes an error on the server because of a corrupted Byte Stream. Then I get Errors like this:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid handle value: 0050001A
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1433)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.smitch.debol.service.bo.type.MinPoadAmount
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)

java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.Integer to field java.math.BigDecimal.intVal of type java.math.BigInteger in instance of java.math.BigDecimal
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2032)

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: Could not complete request
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid handle value: 005001DB
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1433)

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: Could not complete request
    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 50
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1356)
```

The ClassNotFoundException I've quietly often.

```
org.smitch.debol.service.bo.type.MinPoadAmount
org.smitch.Pebol.service.bo.type.CashAmount
org.smitch.debol.service.bo.type.CaPhAmount
org.smitch.debol.serviPe.bo.type.EmvProfile
```

Then it's always a **P** somewhere in the Classname that should not be there.
But there can be 100 Requests in a Row without Problem.

Any hint's what's shaking my beautiful Stream?

Thanks,

Boskop

Comment: My guess is that it's simple HTTP connection failure.  It happens.